# How to delete dynamic field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I am building script where I can add some dynamic fields and then delete it if I want. But I can't delete that first el class in my script, because it deletes all within `input_fields_container` class. How to do it correctly? Here's my code:

```
<div class="input_fields_container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary add_more_button" style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            @lang('main.add more fields')
        </button>
    </div>
    @foreach(Auth::user()->test as $data)
    <div class="el">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">@lang('main.test')</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="test[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $data->test }}" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields_limit      = 10; //set limit for maximum input fields
        var x = 1; //initialize counter for text box
        $('.add_more_button').click(function(e){ //click event on add more fields button having class add_more_button
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields_limit){ //check conditions
                x++; //counter increment
                $('.input_fields_container').append('<div class="el"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label">@lang('main.test')</label><div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" name="test[]" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label"></div></div><div><a href="#" class="remove_field" style="margin-left:10px;">@lang('main.delete')</a></div></div>');
            }
        });  
        $('.input_fields_container').on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text links
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parents().eq(1).remove(); x--;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: is your problem just about deleting first el class?

Comment: yup, i want to delete closest but it deletes all code what u see here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML in your append is structured wrong. Your div for the remove_field is not inside the '.el' div.

Try this...

```
$('.input_fields_container').append('<div class="el"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Main.test</label><div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" name="test[]" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label"></div><div><a href="#" class="remove_field" style="margin-left:10px;">main.delete</a></div></div></div>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chadsaun/Ljxw03Lp/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You need to change the `class="el"` to `id="el"`

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove_field', function () {
   $('#el').closest('#el').remove();
});
```

Comment: Ok, it works. But after clicking remove my page change position to 0,0, why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's something with the CSS

Comment: on another page i have this script as in first post and everything works fine.
Edit: it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can give that 'a' tag an onclick function by id in the for loop. and one id for div with class name 'el' something like this code below:

```
     $('.add_more_button').click(function(e){ //click event on add more fields button having class add_more_button
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(x < max_fields_limit){ //check conditions
                        x++; //counter increment
                        $('.input_fields_container').append('<div class="el" id='el" + id +"'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">@lang('main.test')</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" name="test[]" class="form-control"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label"></div>
                           </div>
                           <div>
                           <a href="#" class="remove_field" onclick="deleteInput('"+id+ "')"  style="margin-left:10px;">@lang('main.delete')</a>
                           </div>
                           </div>');
                    }
                });
```

And then you can add the deletInput function like this code below, in this function the method finds div with the id of el+id and remove it:

```
function deleteInput(id){
            $('#el'+id+'').remove();
        }
```

Remember your id for el element must be unique.
This is the concept of removing inputs by id.

Hope this would help!